# XMLHttpRequest cannot load URL Invalid HTTP status code 401 AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, cors, restful-authentication

I'm trying to get some data from an API using angular.js and in google chrome app - Advanced Rest Client I tested the headers and it is working fine, I get a 200 response and I can see the data, but when I run my app I get the following error:

Refused to set unsafe header "Access-Control-Request-Headers"
ionic.bundle.js:17607 OPTIONS http://api.representemais.com.br/api/clientes 401 (Authorization Required)
    (index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.representemais.com.br/api/clientes. Invalid HTTP status code 401

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

    /* CATEGORIES */
    .factory('ServiceClientes', ['$http', function ($http) {

        var endpoint = 'http://api.repmais.com/api/clients';

        var token = "99KI9Gj68CgCf70deM22Ka64chef2C40Gm2lFJ2J0G9JkD0bFAcbFfd19MfacGf3FFm8CM1hG0eDiIk8";
        var credencial = "rm@w.com.br:cd87cd5ef753a06ee79fc75ds7cfe66c";
        var origem = "mobile";


        return {

            getAll: function () {
                return $http.get(endpoint, {
                    headers: {

                    'X-API-TOKEN': token,
                    'X-API-CREDENCIAL': credencial,
                    'X-API-ORIGEM': origem,
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' : 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : 'http://localhost:8100',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
                    'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'X-Requested-With, accept, content-type',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                    }
                });
            }
 }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to manually set headers that are supposed to be set by the browser.

> The above headers are controlled by the user agent to let it control those aspects of transport. This guarantees data integrity to some extent.

https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/xhr/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#dom-xmlhttprequest-setrequestheader

Also, the Access-Control-Allow headers are supposed to be used by servers. You can read more about it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 0):

```
 $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};
```

> add that to your app.config, if that doesn't work, try posting the request from the controller no from the service